# Read an array from a CSV file

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io

(Edit, updated code)
I am trying to complete this assignment that reads an array from a CSV file and returns an array list of cars. I am passing two of the five tests but I think my problem is the "return null" at the end. I not exactly sure what I am supposed to return. I've tried going through our lecture notes and asked the professor and they were both no help. I am not asking for the answer, I just need to be pointed in the right direction

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Practice reading CSV files
 * 
 * @author 250 Instructors
 * @version Feb 2017
 *
 */
public class CarsForSale {

/**
 * Read an array from CSV file
 * 
 * @param aFile
 *            - string pointing to file
 * @return the array list of Cars; return null if error encountered
 */
public static ArrayList<Car> getCarsFromCSVFile(String aFile) {
    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    
    File file = new File(aFile);
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String car = scan.nextLine();
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to open file " + aFile);
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    return cars; 
}

}
```

Comment: I think you want to return an actual array list, for example `return cars;` if your code succeeds. Your return type is `ArrayList<Car>` not `ArrayList<String>` so you will need to create Car objects and add them to an array rather than just making an array of strings `ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();`

Comment: @sorifiend Based on the comment you made before that one I noticed that I needed to change `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Car>`. This allowed me to pass one more test and it's going in the right direction now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is with what and where you're returning. The JavaDoc says:

> @return the array list of Cars; return null if error encountered

Any errors should be caught by your catch block, meaning you want to return null at the end of that catch block (if you ever enter it).

To return the ArrayList of Cars, first you need to make sure you're creating Car objects with the input you're getting from the file, then add those objects to the ArrayList (not strings like you currently have).

If everything goes good, you should return the ArrayList of Car objects at the end of the try block.

```
try {
    // read from file, create Car objects and add the objects to an ArrayList

    return Cars;
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc comment says:

> @return the array list of Cars; return null if error encountered

If you return `null` from the catch block and `cars` at the end of the method, you will satisfy those requirements.

```
try {
    // read from file
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception

    return null;
}
```

You can read more about returning from catch blocks [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/can-we-have-a-return-statement-in-the-catch-or-finally-blocks-in-java).

Comment: Thank you for this. I realized that my last if statement was unnecessary and I condensed it within the catch. Now I am trying to figure out the while loop within the `try`. I know that car is not a string so I need to change that but I am having trouble with the `String car = scan.nextLine();` line. I edited it and it is now `Car car = scan.nextLine();` but it is not a string so something is not right with it.

Comment: @BrandonBerry You have not shown is what the Car class looks like, please update your question to include it, however, it should have a method to create a `new` car object. For example `Car car = new Car(scan.nextLine());`. Here is the official java tutorial about how objects and classes work: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Comment: @sorifiend I updated the original question with my current code

Comment: @BrandonBerry I meant the `Car` class (It will be in a different class file called `Car` like this `public class Car{...` ). That class should have an initilizer that accepts a string to create a new `Car` object.